# How to see the contents of each partition in an RDD in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I want to learn a little more about how pyspark partitions data. I need a function such that:

```
a = sc.parallelize(range(10), 5)
show_partitions(a)

#output:[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]] (or however it partitions)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [glom](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#glom) function is what you are looking for:

> glom(self): Return an RDD created by coalescing all elements within each partition into a list.

```
a = sc.parallelize(range(10), 5)
a.glom().collect()
#output:[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val data = List((1,3),(1,2),(1,4),(2,3),(3,6),(3,8))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
rdd.glom().collect()
         .foreach(a => {
                         a.foreach(println);
                         println("=====")})
```

in this way , you can check how the data is partitioned